# Laravel command queue:work freezes in windows

Tags: windows, laravel, terminal, command

i created an event which is when fired a listener dispatches a job with delay time of 20 seconds. the sole purpose of that job is to send the email to the user when he tries to login. the problem is that when i run

```
php artisan queue:work
```

nothing shows in the terminal and neither job is delayed. but however email is send to the user. for more info i am using telescope for debugging.
my driver is database.[output][1]

my code for job

```
class sendEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $user;
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user=$user;

    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        \Mail::to($this->user)->send(new \App\Mail\subscriptionLetters());
    }
}
```

when job is dispatched

````
   public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  UserLoggedIn  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(UserLoggedIn $event)
    {
        \App\Jobs\sendEmail::dispatch($event->user)->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(20));
    }
}
```[command in terminanl][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDADW.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8EFm.png
````

Answer (score 0):

run

```
php artisan config:clear
```

and after that shutdown the development server of laravel
after that run

```
php artisan serve
```

now you will see your

```
php artisan queue:work
```

working ,remember run queue:work in a separate terminal